# TensorFlow - создание модели для обучения (.pb) распознавания речи и преобразования в текст

Tags: java, android, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, распознавание-речи

помогите пожалуйста разобраться с TensorFlow. 
Мне нужно создать Android приложение для распознавания команд управления, но сделать это нужно с использованием нейронных сетей. Я собираюсь использовать  библиотеку TensorFlow для упрощения задачи. 
На [git-hub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo)   я нашёл реализацию Speech Recognition (speech to text) (классы: [SpeechActivity.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/SpeechActivity.java), [RecognizeCommands.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/RecognizeCommands.java), [TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java)), но там используется обученная модель ([список слов](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/android/app/src/main/assets/conv_actions_labels.txt)), мне нужно сделать или переобучить модель на нужный мне список слов (числа и команды для андроид, такие как: "яркость", "громкость" и т.д., например, если говорю "яркость 50" - яркость смартфона устанавливается на 50).
Так вот, подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать, может кто сталкивался с созданием\переобучением моделей нейронных сетей, буду очень благодарен!
P.S. На JAVA

Comment: На сколько мне известно, нет способа обучать сейчас модельку на android. Можно только использовать готовые модели, а готовые модели уже создают люди работающие с big data.  Поэтому вопрос задавать надо скорее всего не в андроид ветку

Comment: TensorFlow для Android:  https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tfmobile/android_build